# Efficiently Compare Successive Characters in String

Tags: java, text, dictionary, nlp

I'm doing some text analysis, and need to record the frequencies of character transitions in a `String`. I have *n* categories of characters: for the sake of example, `isUpperCase()`, `isNumber()`, and `isSpace()`.

Given that there are *n* categories, there will be *n^2* categories of transitions, e.g. "`isUpperCase()` --> `isUpperCase()`", "`isUpperCase` --> `isLetter()`", "`isLetter()` --> `isUpperCase()`", etc.

Given a block of text, I would like to record the number of transitions that took place. I would imagine constructing a `Map` with the transition types as the `Keys`, and an `Integer` as each `Value`.

For the block of text "`TO`", the `Map` would look like `[isUpper -> isUpper : 1, isUpper -> isSpace : 1]`

The part I cannot figure out, though, is how to construct a `Map` where, from what I can see, the `Key` would consist of 2 `boolean` methods.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create an `enum` that represents character types - you need a way to get a character type `enum` given a character. I'm sure there are better ways to do that than what I have done below but that is left as an exercise to the reader.

Next create a method that takes the previous and current characters and concatenates their types into a unique `String`.

Finally loop over the input string and hey presto.

```
private static enum CharacterType {

    UPPER {
        @Override
        boolean isA(final char c) {
            return Character.isUpperCase(c);
        }
    },
    LOWER {
        @Override
        boolean isA(final char c) {
            return Character.isLowerCase(c);
        }
    },
    SPACE {
        @Override
        boolean isA(final char c) {
            return Character.isWhitespace(c);
        }
    },
    UNKOWN {
        @Override
        boolean isA(char c) {
            return false;
        }
    };

    abstract boolean isA(final char c);

    public static CharacterType toType(final char c) {
        for (CharacterType type : values()) {
            if (type.isA(c)) {
                return type;
            }
        }
        return UNKOWN;
    }
}

private static String getTransitionType(final CharacterType prev, final CharacterType current) {
    return prev + "_TO_" + current;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    final String myString = "AAaaA Aaa  AA";
    final Map<String, Integer> countMap = new TreeMap<String, Integer>() {
        @Override
        public Integer put(final String key, final Integer value) {
            final Integer currentCount = get(key);
            if (currentCount == null) {
                return super.put(key, value);
            }
            return super.put(key, currentCount + value);
        }
    };
    final char[] myStringAsArray = myString.toCharArray();
    CharacterType prev = CharacterType.toType(myStringAsArray[0]);
    for (int i = 1; i < myStringAsArray.length; ++i) {
        final CharacterType current = CharacterType.toType(myStringAsArray[i]);
        countMap.put(getTransitionType(prev, current), 1);
        prev = current;
    }
    for (final Entry<String, Integer> entry : countMap.entrySet()) {
        System.out.println(entry);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
LOWER_TO_LOWER=2
LOWER_TO_SPACE=1
LOWER_TO_UPPER=1
SPACE_TO_SPACE=1
SPACE_TO_UPPER=2
UPPER_TO_LOWER=2
UPPER_TO_SPACE=1
UPPER_TO_UPPER=2
```

Running the method on the content of your question (825 chars) took 9ms.

Comment: First off, I just want to say Thank You. I don't know if this will work yet, because I need to learn more about `enum`, but it looks awesome!

Comment: It's a very elegant solution indeed. I like it!

Answer (score 0):

If you think most of the transitions will be present, then a 2 dimension Array would work best:

```
int n = _categories.size();
int[][] _transitionFreq = new int[n][n];
```

If you think it will be a parse array, then a map will be more efficient in terms of memory usage, but less efficient in terms of performance.

It's a trade-off you'll have to make depending on your data and the number of character types.